# asp.net mvc secure folder containing random file extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, directory, file-extension

I am working on Asp.net MVC application.  Application contain a folder which need to be secured from unauthorized access.  Customer can copy file with any extension to this folder.  Customer doesn't want unauthorized person (person without log in) to download the file by directly accessing the file in browser's URL.

I cannot use httpHandler as extension of the file is not known to us beforehand.
I also tried with keeping separate web.config with  `<deny users="?"/>` in it's authorization section.  But it works only for known extension, for unknown extension it gives following error,

```
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
```

Can some one suggest how handle this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the physical files on the server in the secured folder, you could store them as binary arrays in a database. And then use a common handler to fetch the files.

Eg: https://example.com/SecuredFolder/Readfile?id=12345

Then you can set the `Content-Type` in the response programatically.